# The Great Outdoors self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find a few questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: If those are random, we're in trouble - seem to be universally half-assed (and yes, one of them includes a poor answer from me).

Comment: Yeah, overall quality does need to improve.

Answer (score 4):

[Minimum equipment recommendations for hammock camping](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/minimum-equipment-recommendations-for-hammock-camping)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with where the line is on self-promotion, but I feel like it's a solid Q&A.

Comment: IMO - for an answer that good I'm okay with a bit of self promotion since it's clear to me that the question was not a setup.

Answer (score 4):

[Is it legal to light bonfires on UK beaches?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1329/is-it-legal-to-light-bonfires-on-uk-beaches)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Well I think this is a good question, but then again I'm biased...! :P

Answer (score 3):

[How can I prevent my sun glasses from fogging up when skiing?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1317/how-can-i-prevent-my-sun-glasses-from-fogging-up-when-skiing)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good, relevant question and while not the most comprehensive answer around it's definitely ok. I'm not an expert in the area so it may well be that simple either way!

Comment: I love this question.  Glasses fogging up is such a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

[What is the minimum gap needed for a windscreen on a cat can stove?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/what-is-the-minimum-gap-needed-for-a-windscreen-on-a-cat-can-stove)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question, answer isn't the best but again I'd say it's better than no answer at all.

Comment: @berry120 -- I'm in the process of testing solutions and will post all my data when I'm done ;)

Comment: @RussellSteen Awesome - sounds good! That was not intended as a criticism of your answer btw :-)

Comment: No judgement taken.  We're talking here to improve, so even if it is criticism, it's good.  Negative feedback is still feedback and 100% than NO feedback ;)

Answer (score 1):

[How can I tell when pemmican has spoiled?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/how-can-i-tell-when-pemmican-has-spoiled)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The question is a good and valid one, but I'm not convinced on the answer - no-one really seems to know for sure...

Comment: @berry120 -- Yeah, I haven't been able to find a valid answer at all.  The best I can get anywhere is "if it make you want to hurl when you start to eat it, don't"

Answer (score -2):

[Good books to learn survival?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/good-books-to-learn-survival)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this question - seems to invite discussion rather than ask for a particular answer... unless there turns out to be a definitive guide to survival in the Norwegian wild (doesn't seem likely... in English anyways)

Answer (score -2):

[Legality of "semi-permanent" wooden structures in state and national forests in the US](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/legality-of-semi-permanent-wooden-structures-in-state-and-national-forests-in)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Good question, poor answer IMHO

Comment: @Ryley -- Yeah, I agree.

Comment: Agreed - though it's one that is difficult to answer correctly without an authoritative source, so perhaps in that sense that answer FWIW is better than no answer.

Comment: The more I think of this, I think it's actually a bad question because it's *unaswerable*.  Legality of a permanent structure on state land is a VERY localized thing, often to the park level.  What is legal in on one plot of state land may be illegal on state land 10 miles down the road.  It's a bad question because there is no answer, and we can very logically conclude there is no single valid answer.

Comment: @RussellSteen Ah, but you only know it's unanswerable directly because of extra knowledge around that area - I would argue it's a perfectly valid question, it's just the answer (or an answer) should state that it's very difficult to answer directly for the reasons you stated. That way people searching and coming across that question will still get the information they need.